# xpath expression to select text from link

Tags: xpath

I have such content of html file:

`<a class="bf" title="Link to book" href="/book/229920/">book name</a>`

Help me to construct xpath expression to get link text (book name).
I try to use `/a`, but expression evaluates without results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
//a
```

?

More specific is better:

```
//a[@class='bf' and starts-with(@href, '/book/')]
```

Note that this selects the `<a>` *element*. In your host environment it's easy to extract the text value of that node via standard DOM methods (like the `.textContent` property).

To select the actual text node, see the other answers in this thread.

Comment: your answer helped me more, but without starts-with parameter!

Comment: @alex: It was just meant to be an example of "more specific is better". ;)

Answer (score 17):

If the context is the entire document you should probably use `//` instead of `/`. Also you  may (not sure about that) need to get down one more level to retrieve the text.

I think it should look like this

```
//a/text()
```

**EDIT:** As Tomalak pointed out it's `text()` not `text`

Comment: There is no `<text>` element under `<a>`. You mean `//a/text()`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends also on the rest of your document. If you use `//` in the beginning all the matching nodes will be returned, which might be too many results in case you have other links in your document.

Apart from that a possible xpath expression is `//a/text()`.

The `/a` you tried only returns the `a`-tag itself, if it is the root element. To get the link text you need to append the `/text()` part.