# Why doesn't google chrome print the text() of my XPath query?

Tags: google-chrome, xpath

I am trying to extract the texts of an xpath query, `$x('//td[@class="first"]/a/text()')` in Chrome but then when I run this command I see `text` as opposed to the actual text value of the anchor links.

When I run `s.toString()` I am seeing `[object Text],[object Text],[object Text],[object Text]...`.

How can I get their string value in the xpath?

[image]

Comment: I'm no xpath-expert, but this looks useful: [xpath expression to select text from link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2311502/717088). Also, is your issue **_only_** present in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because `$x()` returns an array of HTML or XML elements matching the given XPath expression. It is a shortcut for document.evaluate().
If you want to get exact element, just get it by position out of the array

> $x(element)[0]

This may be helpful: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#xpath

If you want to print(or do any other stuff) all text elements found by locator in console - you can just call `forEach` function:

```
$x('//a/text()').forEach(function(el){console.log(el)})
$x('//a/text()').forEach(el => console.log(el))
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So if I am planning to join all the strings from this xpath expression into a string separated by '\n', how should I go about doing so? For the record, `texts = $x('//td[@class="first"]/a/text()'); var q=[]; for (var i=0; i<texts.length; ++i) { q.push(texts[i]) }; q.join('\n')` returns [object Text] all over again

Comment: Try this: `$x("//td[@class="first"]/a").map(function(el){return el.text}).join("\n")`

Comment: You can also use `text.trim()` to trim spaces

Answer (score 9):

Use the following command under these circumstances:
- The element's text is stored in data.
- You want to trim leading and trailing whitespace from the data.
- You want to easily copy paste the output from the console delimited by break-line.

```js
console.log($x(<pathToElement>/text()').map(function(el){return el.data.trim()}).join("\n"))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use .map(a=>a.textContent) to extract your need.

```
$x('//td[@class="first"]/a/text()').map(a=>a.textContent)
```